# Синтаксические функции в PHP

Tags: php

Есть ли в PHP функции, с помощью которых можно:

1. Добавить символ в конец значения переменной ?
2. Прочесть последний символ значения переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
substr($переменная,strlen($переменная)-1,1); //последний символ
$переменная=$переменная . "символ";          //Добавление символа в конец переменной.
```

Comment: Альтернатива    

    $var = substr($var, -1, 1); // или $var{strlen($var)-1}
    $var .= 's';

Comment: Привычка с паскалей все писать подробно)))

Answer (score 0):

1. Если конкатенировать к содержимому переменной, то просто `.` (точка)
2. `subsrt` - читай про неё, так будет лучше

Comment: Опередил))

Comment: Не хотел писать полное решение, потому что если бы написал полное, то при постановке задачи выделение двух последних символов, снова был бы вопрос. Надеюсь @Zow почитал документацию, а не просто скопировал.